# How to get a sub-field of a struct type map, in the search response of YQL query in Vespa?

Tags: yql, vespa

**Sample Data:**

```
"fields": {
    "key1":0,
    "key2":"no",
    "Lang": {
        "en": {
            "firstName": "Vikrant",
            "lastName":"Thakur"
        },
        "ch": {
            "firstName": "维克兰特",
            "lastName":"塔库尔"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
"fields": {
  "Lang": {
      "en": {
          "firstName": "Vikrant",
          "lastName":"Thakur"
       }
  }
}
```

I have added the following in my search-definition **demo.sd**:

```
struct lang {
  field firstName type string {}
  field lastName type string {}
}

field Lang type map <string, lang> {
  indexing: summary
  struct-field key {
    indexing: summary | index | attribute
  }
}
```

I want to write a yql query something like this (This doesn't work):

```
http://localhost:8080/search/?yql=select Lang.en from sources demo where key2 contains 'no';
```

**My temporary workaround approach**

I have implemented a custom searcher in **MySearcher.java**, through which I am able to extract the required sub-field and set a new field 'defaultLang', and remove the 'Lang' field. The response generated by the searcher:

```
"fields": {
  "defaultLang": {
      "firstName": "Vikrant",
      "lastName":"Thakur"
  }
}
```

I have written the following in MySearcher.java:

```
for (Hit hit: result.hits()) {
    String language = "en";  //temporarily hard-coded
    StructuredData Lang = (StructuredData) hit.getField("Lang");
    Inspector o = Lang.inspect();
    for (int j=0;j<o.entryCount();j++){
        if (o.entry(j).field("key").asString("").equals(language)){
            SlimeAdapter value = (SlimeAdapter) o.entry(j).field("value");
            hit.setField("defaultLang",value);
            break;
        }
    }
    hit.removeField("Lang");
}
```

**Edit-1: A more efficient way instead is to make use of the Inspectable interface and Inspector, like above (Thanks to @Jo Kristian Bergum)**

But, in the above code, I am having to loop through all the languages to filter out the required one. I want to avoid this O(n) time-complexity and make use of the map structure to access it in O(1). (Because the languages may increase to 1000, and this would be done for each hit.)

All this is due to the **StructuredData** data type I am getting in the results. StructureData doesn't keep the Map Structure and rather gives an array of JSON like:

```
[{
  "key": "en",
  "value": {
    "firstName": "Vikrant",
    "lastName": "Thakur"
  }
}, {
  "key": "ch",
  "value": {
    "firstName": "维克兰特",
    "lastName": "塔库尔"
  }
}]
```

Please, suggest a better approach altogether, or any help with my current one. Both are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The YQL sample query I guess is to illustrate what you want as that syntax is not valid. Picking a given key from the field Lang of type map  can be done as you do in your searcher but deserializing into JSON and parsing the JSON is probably inefficient as StructuredData implements the Inspectable interface and you can inspect it directly without the need to go through JSON format. See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/inspecting-structured-data.html

Comment: Thank you, @Jo Kristian Bergum for your answer. I created the Inspector object using the Inspectable interface. But, that too creates an array with 2 entries (for the two languages with keys "key" and "value") like the one I mentioned above, and I have to loop through the entries to pick a specific key. I don't understand why Vespa is deserializing the map data type on its own. Please, help.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that handling of map or weighted sets is not optimal when working on Hit field data.  AFAIK you are not able to do a direct lookup in the map but with my suggestion you avoid producing JSON, then parsing the JSON when the data could be accessed directly (Iterating though):

Comment: Ok. I agree this would be more efficient. Can you tell me if it's somehow possible at the YQL level itself? Maybe by changing my search-definition data types, indexing, or a completely different Data Architecture. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No, there is no support for this via YQL to only chose a given key in a map for display. As far as I can tell you have an optimal solution already (given the limitations of the field api).